# What is the difference between Window.load and document.readyState

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-events

I have one question; In my ASP.NET MVC web application  have to do certain validation once page and all controls got loaded.

In Javascript I was using below line of code for calling a method:

```
window.load = JavascriptFunctionName ;
```

Someone from my team asked me not used above line of code,
instead use JQuery to do the same:

```
 document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function() {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            CheckThis();

        }
    });
```

Please help me in understanding what is the difference between two.
When I tested by keeping alert in both jQuery check is executing first and calling the `CheckThis` function where as `window.load` is taking some time and executing after it.
Please suggest

Comment: Here's a pen that shows the order in which all events fire, the jQuery approach isn't necessarily the right choice under all circumstances: [codepen.io/pen/jagxdb](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jagxdb?editors=0010).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`window.load` - This runs when all content is loaded, including images.

`document.ready` - This runs when the DOM is ready, all the elements are on the page and ready to do, but the images aren't necessarily loaded.

Here's the jQuery way to do `document.ready`:

```
$(function() {
  CheckThis();
});
```

If you wanted to still have it happen on `window.load`, do this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  CheckThis();
});
```

Comment: [`readyState` has 3 options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) `loading`, `interactive` and `complete`, which one are you talking about in here? `complete` according to the docs means that all `sub-resources` (including images I suppose...) are loaded. Then it says it indicates the `load `event has been fired.

Comment: Might need an update. Using load like that was already deprecated but has now been removed.

Answer (score 5):

`window.load` triggered when your page completely loaded (with images, banners, etc.), but `document.readyState` triggered when DOM is ready

Answer (score 3):

The ready handler executes as soon as the DOM has been created, without waiting for all external resources to be loaded.

Since you've using jQuery, a more concise, browser agnostic, and widely used syntax for it is:

```
$(function(){  
   CheckThis();
});
```